# How to serialize only a subset of an one-to-many relationship?

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have an entity `Point` with hundreds of related `Comment`s. (This is a simplification, in the real problem `Comment` is a complex, hard to explain and irrelevant class)

In my REST API I need to return *all* the points with the comments that meet some restrictions (for example, between a time interval).

How can I restrict the comments that are serialized and returned? I'm using Symfony2 with [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) and [JMSSerializer](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle).

Return first the points and then query for the comments of each point is not an option. In the real problem I need this information for intensive computacion.

Comment: Is filtering the related comments prior to serializing in a custom repository method a valid option for you? performance-wise it would make sense to fetch only the relations you need from database.

Answer (score 2):

Set @Accessor(getter="getCommentsRestricted"), and getCommentsRestricted() method will retrieve only comments matching your criteria. If the criteria is dynamic, you have to set them on the object prior to serialization.